# Impossible to return a simple function in a variable

Tags: php

Basically I just wanted to find the sum of a multidimensional array.

And I came across this rather funny situation:

```
<?php
    $tab = [["19", "20"], ["19", "20"]];

    var_dump(array_sum(array_map(function($item)
    {
        return floatval($item[0]); 
    }, $tab)));

    $sum = array_sum(array_map(function($item)
    {
        return floatval($item[0]); 
    }, $tab));

    var_dump($sum);
```

And this is the output :

```
float(38)
NULL
```

I don't understand why these two lines are different.

I use PHP 7.1.19 on Mac OS.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: For me they are not different, if I execute your code I get two identical lines of output. Using a current standard php-7.2, but on a normal Linux system, not MacOS.

Comment: Ditto. https://3v4l.org/NLC6N

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem for  php version you mentioned:- https://3v4l.org/sMXi4

Comment: Same here both are the same

Comment: both is same in  PHP 7.1.19

Comment: Even on windows I get 2 x 38

Comment: 7.2 mint seems to output same values for code ^^ haven't got access to 7.1.19 :S

Comment: Are you sure with your problem?

Comment: I guess it's not the whole code. The only situation I can think of, for `$sum` to be `NULL`, is when `$tab` is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, you helped me by telling me that it was working for you on the same version as me.

I looked at the content of my file and saw a character with a slightly high value:
[image]

The "c2 a0" is an unbreakable space...

As it is quite possible to use unicode characters as variable names, PHP considered that the second variable was "$sum " (a `var_dump($sum );` works!)

Comment: Hah, nice one. I guess any decent IDE would catch it.